# CSS changes unexpectedly when I open IE Developer Tools

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, ie-developer-tools

I am currently testing a site on IE8 (running on a Virtual Machine).

The site uses some background images inside :before and :after elements, which are inside a media query:

```
@media (min-width: 980px) {

    .box:after {
        ...
        background: url('../images/assets/home-create-background.png') bottom right no-repeat;
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm using [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to provide support for media queries on IE8. 
The rules inside the media query are applied as soon as the page loads (ie: respond.js is actually working). However, this images are not displayed.

The funny thing:  **if I open IE Developer Tools (eg. pressing F12), the images are suddenly displayed.**

**Anyone has experienced something similar?
Do you guys have any idea or direction to explore?**

---

**Edit:**
I was finally able to fix this problem adding content to the :after pseudo-element (I was already applying this rule, but not inside the media query and, for some reason, it wasn't applied on IE)

```
    .box:after {
        ...
        background: url('../images/assets/home-create-background.png') bottom right no-repeat;
        content: " ";
        ...
    }
```

In any case, I believe it's interesting to know why the layout was changing when I opened the Dev Tools...

Comment: Would you add a small test case to your question please?

Comment: I have seen this question before.

Comment: I've noticed it with JavaScript, so I'm not entirely surprised to see it happening with CSS as well. Non-web people really have no idea how much pain IE has caused us over the years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of pain points with IE can be identified so it is worth checking the following:

1. Any `console.log()` statements will force IE to not render anything until the developer tools are shown.
2. When you open up IE Dev tools, it is in a different compatibility mode by default than the default view that you are used to.

Comment: +1 Any console.log() statements will force IE to not render anything until the developer tools are shown

Comment: 1: This didn't seem to be the problem in my case (I tryed removing all console.logs). However, it's very interesting to know that.

2: No, I was running on normal mode (IE8) but, again, another good point!